# Why is the value of second parameter I'm passing in JQuery Autocomplete always zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to pass an additional parameter into my controller.  Everything works fine except that I can't seem to obtain the value of the second parameter.

My controller expects the following two parameters:

```
public JsonResult GetProductList(string term, int manufacturerid)
```

My autocomplete is coded as follows:

```
 $("#InternalProductNumber").catcomplete({
   delay: 0,
   min_length: 3,
   source: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Proposal")',
   data: {
      term: $("#InternalProductNumber").val(),
      manufacturerid: $("#ManufacturerId").val()
    }, 
     select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#ProductId").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#InternalProductNumber").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#SellPrice").val(ui.item.sellprice);
        return false;
      }
   });
```

the Term is always passed in correctly, but the manufacturerid (it's a dropdown list) is always zero.  If I place an alert in the select function I get a non-zero result which tells me I've got a value.

```
alert($("#ManufacturerId").val());
```

******* EDIT *******

I added the code as suggested which now looks as follows:

```
 $("#InternalProductNumber").catcomplete({
            delay: 0,
            min_length: 3,
            source: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Proposal")'+ `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert('@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Proposal")' + `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`);
                $("#ProductId").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#InternalProductNumber").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#SellPrice").val(ui.item.sellprice);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I'm still getting 0 for the manufacturerid parameter. Here's the result of the Network tab in the developer options.

[image]

I added the Alert after the selection just to double-check and I'm getting the correct results in the Alert.

[image]

Not sure where to go from here.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

-- Val

Comment: I think, because of your backend is expecting integer  `manufacturerid` and you pass `manufacturerid` as string, that is why your parameter is parsed to 0. Try this: 

`manufacturerid: +$("#ManufacturerId").val()` in your `catcomplete` function's `data` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see `term` is an jQuery built-in parameter from text box `InternalProductNumber`. The `term` will always appear in your method `public JsonResult GetProductList(string term, int manufacturerid)`.

I was able to reproduce your code in ASP.NET Core project and got the same result `manufacturerid = 0`. My code was slightly different:

```
$("#InternalProductNumber").autocomplete({
           minLength: 3,
           source: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Home")',
           data: {
               term: $("#InternalProductNumber").val(),
               manufacturerid: $("#ManufacturerId").val()
           },
           select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log("In select function.");
                return false;
           }
       });
```

I debugged and in Watch window I could see `Request.QueryString = '?term=aaa'` and no `manufacturerid`.

**Solution**

```
$("#InternalProductNumber").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    min_length: 3,
    source: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Proposal")'+ `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#ProductId").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#InternalProductNumber").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#SellPrice").val(ui.item.sellprice);
        return false;
    }
  });

function ManufacturerId_OnChange() {
    $("#InternalProductNumber").catcomplete('option', 'source', '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Home")' + `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`);
}
```

After I added `manufacturerid` as QueryString parameter then the function `GetProductList` correctly gets `term` and `manufacturerid`.

**UPDATE**

**About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<body>
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

<input type="text" id="InternalProductNumber" name="InternalProductNumber" />

<br />
<select id="ManufacturerId" name="ManufacturerId"  onchange="ManufacturerId_OnChange();">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(`In 1 ${parseInt($('#ManufacturerId').val())}.`);

    //catcomplete
    
    $("#InternalProductNumber").autocomplete({
       minLength: 3,
       source: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Home")' + `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`,
       select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("In select function.");
            return false;
       }
   });
   function ManufacturerId_OnChange() {
        //catcomplete
        $("#InternalProductNumber").autocomplete('option', 'source', '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Home")' + `?manufacturerid=${$("#ManufacturerId").val()}`);
    }
</script>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProductList(string term, int manufacturerid)
    {
        var strTestJSON = "{ \"test\": 1, \"cat\": 2}";

        return Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strTestJSON));
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied line-for-line what you have and I'm still getting a zero.  Here's the result of my call.  https://localhost:5001/Proposal/GetProductList?manufacturerid=0&term=IBM

Comment: Have you selected something from ManufacturId? Try to debug C# code `GetProductList`. How did you get this url localhost...?

Comment: I edited my post to add the additional details.  To. your question, I did have something selected for ManufacturID.  I got the URL from the network tab in Chrome.  I just don't understand why ManufacturerID is always zero when I make the call to GetProductList but always the selected value everywhere else!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am  still investigating and updated my answer.

Comment: Val, you need to add event handler `onchage` to `select` combo box. Then update `source` for `catcomplete`. I just updated my code in the answer again.

Comment: it works now!  Thank you so much for your help.  Wouldn't have imagined that it would have been this difficult.  Cheers!

Comment: I am glad that can help you !